# Как сделать прозрачный фон у QGraphicsView? Python PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

Всем привет. Хочу сделать интерфейс, как на скриншоте при помощи QGraphicsScene. Но из-за особенностей QGraphicsView он не имеет прозрачного фона. И в итоге по краям белый фон видно. К тому же почему-то картинка не полностью влезает в QGraphicsView и ее можно прокручивать на 1-2 пикселя вверх-вниз.

Что делать? Скриншоты и код прилагаю. (Сама картинка уже имеет прозрачный фон. Белое вокруг картинки - это фон QGraphicsView)

```
class NoteBook(QWidget):

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(NoteBook, self).__init__(parent)

    self.pix = QPixmap("noteBook.png")
    
    scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
    self.pixScene = scene.addPixmap(self.pix.scaled(self.size()))
    
    self.view = QGraphicsView(scene, self)
    self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
    self.view.show()

def paintEvent(self, e):

    self.view.resize(self.size())
    self.pixScene.setPixmap(self.pix.scaled(self.size()))
```

[image: То, что хочу получить]
[image: То, что получается]

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, примерно так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class NoteBook(QWidget):                      
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(NoteBook, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(560, 500)

        self.widget = QWidget()  
        self.widget.setObjectName('Custom_Widget')
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.widget)
        
        self.pix = QPixmap("linux.gif")   
        
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene() 
        self.pixScene = self.scene.addPixmap(self.pix.scaled(self.widget.size().width()*4/5, 
                                             self.widget.size().height()))
        
        self.view = QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.view.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.view.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.view.setRenderHint(QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing)
        
        grid = QGridLayout(self.widget)     
        grid.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.btn = QPushButton("кнопка 1")
        grid.addWidget(self.btn, 1, 0)
        grid.addWidget(QPushButton("кнопка 2"), 2, 0)
        grid.addWidget(self.view, 0, 1, 4, 1)

    def paintEvent(self, e):
        self.view.resize(self.widget.size().width()*4/5, self.widget.size().height())
        self.pixScene.setPixmap(self.pix.scaled(self.widget.size().width()*4/5, 
                                self.widget.size().height()))
        
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.view.resize(self.widget.size().width()*4/5, 
                         self.widget.size().height()) 
        self.scene.setSceneRect(self.rect().x(), self.rect().y(), self.rect().width()*4/5, 
                                self.rect().height())
        

Stylesheet = """
.QWidget {
    border-image: url(cats.jpg);
}
QGraphicsView {
    /* ВАЖНО  ------------>>>>>>> 0 */
    background: rgba(55, 55, 255, 0);                 
    border: None;
}
"""
       
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(Stylesheet)
    ex = NoteBook()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я уже решил проблему просто при помощи setStyleSheet("background: transparent")